# Why didn't Teresa Jump?

Tags: plot-explanation, maze-runner-the-death-cure

In **Maze Runner: The Death Cure**, the city WCKD had taken has fallen to the Right Arm. 
At the end of the battle, after Janson dies, and Thomas and Teresa find themselves on the roof of a building, they kiss and you know what, then a Berg comes with Thomas's team.
Thomas was shot by Janson to the abdomen and becomes very weak, causing Teresa to have to throw him across to the Berg, but what I don't understand is:

Teresa had plenty of time to jump, even before that other building collapsed and crushed the one she was standing on.

Why didn't she jump to the Berg?